# javascript search node by title in collection and return it

Tags: javascript, dom

I wrote a function that tooks an HTMLcollection and a text and iterates that collection searching for a node with that tittle. Then it should return that node.
The problem is that it is returning allways undefined, even when it finds the correct node: In the code you can see there is a console.log that outputs if the current node has that title. On the console I can see one "true" which is what I expect, but the loop does not stop there and the function does not return anything.

```
function searchButtonbyText(group,text){
    for(var i=0;i<group.length;i++){
        for(var j=0; j< group[i].children.length; j++){
            var child = group[i].children[j];
            console.log(child.title == text );
            if( child.title == text ){
                console.log(child);
                return child;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried with simpler functions that just returns certain node with the collection as input and they work correctly. For example

```
function tt(coll){ return coll[7].children[0]}
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I edited the code to correct the error. Now the code is working but the approach on the selected answer is much better.

Comment: `if( child.tite == text ){` maybe title??

Comment: If `tite` was the case, then how console logged `true`?

Comment: @Lepanto we're not seing entire code... just a function... that log can't return true! must return an object

Comment: log true was got from `console.log(child.title == text );` so `tite` might also be a case

Comment: Yes, the problem was the tite thing. I realized it a while after posting the question, but you guys answered before I could delete the question. Thank you very much. This demonstrates that you don't code late in night.

Comment: Yes, the problem was the tite thing. I realized it a while after posting the question, but you guys answered before I could delete the question. Thank you very much. This demonstrates that you don't code late in night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a recursive approach (demo[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/pt567brs/))

```
function searchButtonByText(element, text) {
    var match;
    if(element['title'] && element['title'] === text) {
        return element;
    } else {
        for(var i = 0; i < element.children.length; i++) {
            match = searchButtonByText(element.children[i], text);
            if(match) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return match;
    }
}
```

With the following HTML:

```
<ul id='Group'>
    <li><button title='One'>One</button></li>
    <li><button title='Two'>Two</button></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><button title='A'>A</button></li>
            <li><button title='B'>B</button></li>
            <li><button title='C'>C</button></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><button title='Three'>Three</button></li>
</ul>
```

Then you can invoke it like this:

```
console.log(searchButtonByText(document.getElementById('Group'), 'Two'));
```

It starts at any arbitrary node, and then looks at each child until it finds a match (no matter how nested they are).  Or you can generalize this even further and make the test a callback like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sndp6tt4/)):

```
function searchByFunction(element, matcher) {
    var match;
    if (matcher(element)) {
        return element;
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < element.children.length; i++) {
            match = searchByFunction(element.children[i], matcher);
            if (match) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return match;
    }
}
```

Then you just need to pass a function that returns a true or false value based on any logic you an devise like this:

```
console.log(searchByFunction(document.getElementById('Group'), function(element) {
    return element['title'] && element['title'] === 'C';
}));
```

Finally to address the requirement of dealing with an array of elements (which each might have children) here is a workable solution ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sndp6tt4/2/)):

```
function searchByFunction(element, matcher) {
    var match,
        i;
    if(element.length) {
        for (i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
            match = searchByFunction(element[i], matcher);
            if (match) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (matcher(element)) {
            return element;
        } else {
            if(element.children) {
                for (i = 0; i < element.children.length; i++) {
                    match = searchByFunction(element.children[i], matcher);
                    if (match) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return match;
};
```

Along with a helper function to generate matching functions:

```
function buildTitleMatcher(title) {
    return function(element) {
        return element['title'] && element['title'] === title;
    };
};
```

You can use it with a single element like this:

```
console.log(searchByFunction(document.getElementById('Group'), buildTitleMatcher('C')));
```

Or with an array of elements like this:

```
console.log(searchByFunction(document.getElementsByTagName('li'), buildTitleMatcher('B')));
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jason. This approach is very good! In fact is more than I expected. Recursive functions are not one of my strengths. I will add it to my snippets repository. I heard that JS is very slow with recursive functions, since performance is not a key on my project, what do you know about it?

Comment: Hello Jason. Reviewing your solution I noticed that It expects a single element since my approach was iterating an HTML collection. So your example should be modified to match this situation, by you or by me as an edit to my answer. Thank you

Comment: Regarding my last comment you can use a helper function like this:

function searchButtonInCollection(collection,text){
    for(var i=0; i<collection.length; i++){
        var node = searchButtonByText(collection[i],text);
        if(node) return node;
    }
}

Comment: I added code to deal with arrays as well as nodes with children

Comment: Jason Sperske, A-W-E-S-O-M-E. Your approach is elegant and, in my opinion, takes advantage of one of the best JS features. Thank you very much. If I could give you more points I would.